# Encrypt and Decrypt Cookies on iOS

Tags: ios, cookies, encryption, uiwebview

I'm using a UIWebView to display a webpage. I'd like to know if it's possible to encrypt and decrypt cookies stored on an iOS device. I'm using `NSHTTPCookieStorage` to store my cookie but I noticed that is stored as cleartext in a property list file.

I discovered that it's stored in a path similar to:
`Root/User/Applications/ASDSDF234ASDRSDF234/Library/Cookies/Cookies.plist`

I would like to keep private information, such as usernames, secure.

Comment: You would have to manually encrypt any values before they were added to the cookie.
If there is any client side code i.e. JavaScript that needs access to the cookie data then the JavaScript implementation would have to be able to decrypt them.
Otherwise just keep all the en/decryption in the app.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sandbox mechanism in iOS system for security, so your app data could NOT be read by other apps. So I think you can keep private information in cookie.

Only for the jailbreaked iOS device, there will be the security problem. I think you can encrypt/decrypt your cookie data both in server side.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  We had this same issue come up, and the concern we faced wasn't about other applications using the cookies, but someone who physically steals the device and gets the data out of that file.  It's actually pretty easy to do.  If the cookie has any sensitive data in it, a hacker can get it too.